# How do I install mbboard package (MikTeX, Windows)?

Tags: fonts, packages, installing, metafont

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) didn't help me much, 'cause this package has MF fonts and I don't have an idea to where should they go. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the link you give is enough to work out where the rest of the stuff goes, the `mbboard` package comes with two folders: `texinputs` and `source`.  In your local texmf folder (as described in the link you read) make a new folder inside the `fonts` folder named `source`. Inside that, make a folder called `mbboard` and put all of the contents of the downloaded `source` folder into that new folder.

In the `texinputs` folder, you will find a few files:

`mbboard.sty` goes into `tex\latex\mbboard`
`mbboard.tex` goes into `tex\plain\mbboard`
`mbboard.dcl` goes into `tex\generic\mbboard`

Once you have done this, you will need to refresh the MikTeX package database.

The documentation for the package is the plain TeX file `mbbtest.tex`. Open this file and compile it using *plain tex* (not latex). If you put the resulting pdf into the `doc` folder of your local texmf folder, then the documentation system will find it too. (It might be useful to rename it `mbb-doc.pdf`.)

Comment: This helped. 10x.

Comment: @user2772 Since it solved your problem, it would help to accept the answer.  Thanks.